# Java for loop formatting console

Tags: java, loops

I'm sure that my question could have a better title so sorry in advance. I have a Java project that I am trying to analyze the text in a string. I would like to count the 3 numbers and add them, count the words that begin with an a and display it. count the words that end with an "s" or "s, count the total words, and finally count the sentences. So far i have been able to do everything except when I go to run the program the display is pretty jumbled. Ideally i'd like to keep each section together but for some reason I can't get that to happen.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class TextAnalysisHW {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "This is a long string that   contains numbers like 100, 34.0, 21 and odd symbols like &, %, #. We are supposed to determine how many words this string has in it and also the number of sentences. We are also required to determine how many numbers are in it and sum them all up. Finally, we must count and display all the words that end with  a 's' and start with an 'a'.";


    // create a copy of string
    String temp = text;


    // convert text to lowercase
    temp = temp.toLowerCase();



    // split tokens by one or more spaces
    String [] tokens = temp.split(" +");



    int j;
    int numCount = 0;
    double total = 0;
    int sentCount = 0;

    for (j=0;j<tokens.length;j=j+1) 
        {

            // check to see if token ends with a comma
            if (tokens[j].endsWith(",")==true) 
            {
            // get rid of the comma
                tokens[j]=tokens[j].replaceAll(",","");
            }
            // otherwise check to see if it ends with a period
            else if (tokens[j].endsWith(".")) 
            {
                tokens[j]=tokens[j].replaceAll("\\.","");
                sentCount = sentCount + 1;
            }
            if (tokens[j].matches("-?[0-9]+|-?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+"))
            {
                System.out.println("  Number found: " + tokens[j]);
                numCount++;
                // Convert number into a Double
                double num = Double.parseDouble(tokens[j]);
                total = total + num;
            }

               if(tokens[j].startsWith("a"))
                {
                    //  Print that token and count it 
                    System.out.println("Word starts with a:  "+tokens[j]);

                }
        }

    System.out.println("Sum of the 3 three numbers: " + total);

    System.out.println((tokens.length - numCount) + " words");

    System.out.println(sentCount +" sentences" );

    // main
}
// class
```

}

The code keeps displaying like this:

```
    Word starts with a:  a
    Number found: 100
    Number found: 34.0
    Number found: 21
    Word starts with a:  and
    Word starts with a:  are
    Word starts with a:  and
    Word starts with a:  also
    Word starts with a:  are
    Word starts with a:  also
    Word starts with a:  are
    Word starts with a:  and
    Word starts with a:  all
    Word starts with a:  and
    Word starts with a:  all
    Word starts with a:  a
    Word starts with a:  and
    Word starts with a:  an
    Sum of the 3 three numbers: 155.0
    71 words
    4 sentences
```

So my question is how can I get the first line of display to stay with the rest of the "Word starts with a: ". When I tried to add the "Words that ends with s: " it became mixed in with the other sections. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this has nothing to do with formatting. you can keep a List of output: add all the 'Word starts with' lines in that list. Do the same for all the number related Strings. and at the end of the flow, you can print them in any order you want

Answer (score 0):

Before the for loop, create two lists to store the words and numbers:

```
ArrayList<String> numbersFound = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> prefixAFound = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the if statements, instead of printing out the the things you found, add them to the lists first:

```
if (tokens[j].matches("-?[0-9]+|-?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+"))
{
    numbersFound.add(tokens[j])
    numCount++;
    double num = Double.parseDouble(tokens[j]);
    total = total + num;
}

if(tokens[j].startsWith("a"))
{
    prefixAFound.add(tokens[j])

}
```

After the for loop, add two more for loops to first print all the numbers found, then all the words starting with A:

```
for (String number : numbersFound) {
    System.out.println("Number Found: " + number);
}

for (String prefixA : prefixAFound) {
    System.out.println("Word starts with a: " + prefixA);
}
```